# Нужна помощь по боту вк

Tags: python, vkontakte-api

Запускаю в питоне проверку кода и выдает ошибку:

```
File "D:/.../.../.../main.py", line 17, in <module>
    bot_longpoll = VkBotLongPoll(vk_session)
TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'group_id'
```

Сам код вот:

```
import data
import vk_api
from data import MyVkData
from vk_api.bot_longpoll import VkBotLongPoll, VkBotEventType

login, password = data.LoginAndPassword()

vk_session = vk_api.VkApi(token=" ")
session_api = vk_session.get_api()
bot_longpoll = VkBotLongPoll(vk_session)

# Поиск людей
AGE_FROM = 15
AGE_TO = 60
SEX = 0
CITY = 10
users = session_api.users.search(
    city=CITY,
    sex=SEX,
    age_from=AGE_FROM, age_to=AGE_TO,
    fields='domain',
    count=1,
    sort=1
)
print(users)

IDS = [user['id'] for user in users['items']]
print(IDS)
```

и сразу вопрос еще можно задать вам, надеюсь на помощь, бота хочется сделать, чтобы он находил людей и писал тем, чьи 'ID' находятся в 'IDS'.

Как сделать так, чтобы бот писал людям? пытался так реализовать, но понимаю что глупо это как-то выглядит.

```
for event in bot_longpoll.listen():
if event.type == 'IDS':
   session_api.messages.send(
       user_id = [IDS]
    )
```

Как бы написать правильно код?

Comment: Я понимаю, что надо добавить group_id, но как правильно не знаю

Comment: В тексте ошибки и в [документации](https://vk-api.readthedocs.io/en/latest/bot_longpoll.html#vk_api.bot_longpoll.VkBotLongPoll) сказано, в `VkBotLongPoll()` нужно еще и `group_id` передавать.

Comment: `Я понимаю, что надо добавить group_id, но как правильно не знаю` - например, `VkBotLongPoll(vk_session, "1891251")`.

Comment: Второй вопрос лучше опубликуйте отдельно и подробнее опишите его.